# Chef is now asking for a password instead of using the key provided to configure EC2 server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, chef-infra

We use little chef to adjust server configuration.  I'm not sure if this got updated on my system recently or something but for some reason it is now asking me for a password when I run the command

```
fix node:server.address.that.has.always.worked.fine
```

I have never had to put in a password and I do not think there even is a password for this.  It is an EC2 instance and sshing in is just done using the .pem file.

I'm not sure how to get the fix command to run without asking for a password that doesn't exists and I have never had to put in.

Comment: Not sure if this is specific to Chef. Perhaps you had the SSH key for the EC2 instance be available in the `ssh-agent` before?

Comment: I'll look at that.  I cannot get any type of error output using `--verbose` so I really have no idea where to even look for answers on this or how to debug it.  Thanks for the message, I'll look into that.